# window.location and window.open problem

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, websphere

I can't seem to solve this.

Originally the JSP code had a function in Javascript that would call a jsp from another server:

```
window.open("<%= otherServer %>/ourreports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index"+index,"Foo",options);
```

where `otherServer` was a local server (http://192.168.4.40:8080)
This worked fine, and would pop out a new window with fooreport.jsp.

The task now is to point to a jsp in the same server.
So, I changed it to

```
window.open("/reports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index"+index,"Foo", options);
```

And I would get a *download the file* popup instead of a page

I also tried to do all of the following:

```
window.location = "/reports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index="+index;
window.location.href = "/reports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index="+index;
window.location = "http://localhost:9080/reports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index="+index;
window.location.href = "http://localhost:9080/reports/Company/fooreport.jsp?index="+index;
```

And I still get the popup to download the fooreport.jsp to my computer.

The jsp is well-formed, has the DOCTYPE, the  tags, the <%@ page declarations... It's essentially the same jsp that was being called before

I'm using WebSphere 7.5.4 and java is 1.5

Comment: What's the MIME type (or just `Content-type` HTTP header) the JSP has when it tries to download?

Comment: if you type the addresses in the browser, do they work or do they still show the download ? also if you download the file does it show the rendered pages ? or the source code with the `<%`.. in it ?

Comment: Is `fooreport.jsp?index"+index'` a typo? You should have an `=` between querystring keys and values. As in `fooreport.jsp?index="+index'`

Comment: @Robusto, it was a typo, thx. @Gaby, I never downloaded it, since I would cancel the popup. @Matt Ball, will check the Content-Type and let you know.   Also, another jsp in the same folder is working fine, so I know it's some coding in that particular jsp.

Comment: WebSphere 7.5.4? I think you mean Rational Application Developer as the latest version of WAS is 7.0.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resided in the JSP. 
Calls using window.location and window.open worked fine for other JSPs.

The problem was in the "<% page" declarations.
I deleted them, so don't remember exactly, but it had to do with Content-Type and ISO setting.
I took them all out, left only the "<% page import" declarations, and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` should work if the `Content-Disposition` header of the response is been set to `Attachment`.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourfile.ext");
```

Noted should be that doing this inside a JSP is a bad idea. If the response concerns binary data, JSP may possibly corrupt it. Do this job in a Servlet. JSP is meant to write template text in, [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to write Java code in.

Comment: Yeah, I know... unfortunately I'm updating 4 year old code, where the Servlet just calls the JSP... and you guessed it... all the code is there in <% %> tags.  The final response is a JSP that loads a Crystal Report .rpt

Comment: As long as it is textbased, it may not necessarily malform the data, no. But did setting the content disposition work for you?